# how do I wait for any thread that ends instead of a specific one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

My script has started many threads.  It has kept count.  The maximum number of threads are now running.  There are more to be run.  How can the script wait for *any one* of the running threads to end so it can safely start another one?  It is using `threading.Thread()` to create each thread but that can be changed if there is a better module. I am using Python 3.6.x.

Comment: Use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) you can start a pool of worker threads or processes and not have to worry about which threads/processes are free

Comment: the threads are heavy CPU load.  i do not want to run more at one time than there are CPUs.  the nature of this project is to limit the CPU load so that the work for each gets done as quickly as it can.

Comment: A thread/process that isn't doing anything is not a burden on the CPU in the grand scheme of things

Comment: each thread would either have to be waiting for something or it would be doing its thing, which is a lot of calculations.

Comment: Python is single threaded. Start a worker process for each CPU/virtual CPU and you can be confident that the threads won't impact the other's performance

Comment: you still can't get 5 tasks of work out of 4 CPUs even if using processes.

Comment: You'll get 4 tasks work until they complete and then 1 tasks will run after that?

Comment: Unless you are running into serious performance issues I don't think having an idle process on your machine is going to cause you too much of an issue

Comment: i don't understand these idle processes.  are they going to somehow wake up and run at the right time?  there are many units of work to do.  each could run from 1 minute to 100 minutes of CPU calculations.  i was expecting threads to do it, but i might need to use processes or switch to doing this in C.

Comment: the main code is getting the work units from the network.  it *may* have *many* more to do by the time one of the running ones ends.  it is not workable to pre-start them all as idle processes in advance since the work unit parameters are coming in over the network.

Comment: Starting a new process is not a quick thing... This seems like a case of trying to 
prematurely optimise something. Having multiple processes waiting to accept tasks/work is a proven design, unless you can prove otherwise I would at least try it

Comment: i assume you mean one worker per CPU.  it can't be one worker per unit of work because the work units will be streaming in at random times.  the main thread will keep them if no CPU slots are available, yet.

Comment: Just try something... you're speculating without any evidence. Once you see the actual effect on the server then you can make a decision

Comment: please post an answer describing how you would do this.  each work unit is a specification of the boundaries, increments, and limit of a Mandelbrot set or Julia set to be computed, which will be run in a process as a program i wrote in C.  the results will be written to a file.  when that is done the thread runs a command to upload the file to AWS S3 then quit.

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a pool of processes and pass tasks to them:

```
def processing_task(arg1, arg2):
    ...

from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as worker_pool:  # By default creates processes == number of CPUs
    while True:
        task = some_queue_implementation.get()  # Some blocking method that receives tasks
        worker_pool.apply_async(processing_task, task.arg1, task.arg2)
```

This will create child processes that will be idle until they are passed a task

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code I always use when using threads.

- sets a certain amount of threads;
- ensures that no code coming after the context manager block executes until all threads complete; and
- kills and raises an exception, if one of the child threads throws an exception.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)\
                as executor:
            futures.append(executor.submit(function, args))
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                if future.exception():
                    for child in futures:
                        child.cancel()
                    raise future.exception()
```

> It has kept count

I hope you are using .lock() and .acquire(), ;-)

Comment: these threads are not using any shared resource.  where would they need to lock?  a file name is passed to each, and each processes a different file.  the result is stored in a like file name, different across all threads.

Comment: The CPython interpreter, the default one downloaded from python.com, has a GIL [(global interpreter lock)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which means that only one thread at a time will run

Comment: OK, then i need to use processes.  that's fine.  i still need to do the same logic.

Comment: @Chris is this code for starting *one* process?  the main code will not have the parameters of all the work to do up front; it gets them over a  network socket.  i do not yet see what this code is doing